# blur the background modal when another modal modal is opened with in it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a react component with two modals  like

```
render{
    return(
           <div>
              <ParentModal>
              <ChildModal/>
              </ParentModal>
           </div>

)

}
```

Tried some backdrop css and blur in which i could see both of the modals are getting blured but i want to make only  to be blurred when child modal  is opened

Comment: We would need some more code of yours.. Anyways, inside the state of the Component which renders both Modal you should keep a property `isBlurred` which is then passed as props to `ChildModal`. Then, inside `ChildModal` you could set inline CSS based on the `props.isBlurred` value.

Comment: I solved same issue like this. I used `showChildModal` state inside parentModal and styled parentModal conditionally like this `style={{ filter: showChildModal ? "blur(5px)" : "none" }}`

Answer (score -1):

CSS filter:blur affects all children. 
You will need something like this:

```
render{
return(
       <div>
          <CommonParent>
              <ParentModal/>
              <ChildModal/>
          </CommonParent>
       </div>
```

)}

and then you can blur only the parent

Comment: But, how will you blur previous siblings with only CSS?